# Não consigo complementar os dados da tabela C#

Tags: c#

Estou clicando um sistema de podologia bem simples com 2 áreas, uma sendo apenas para registrar o clientes e outra para todos os procedimentos que ele irá fazer. A área de registro funcionar perfeitamente com gravar e atualizar dos dados. Já na hora de alimentar o procedimento que o paciente fez dar erro e não vai para o banco de dados SQL Server.

**Código em C#**

```
 private void BntAlterar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                try
                {
                                     
                   
                   string Pos_Trabalho = txtPTrabalho.Text;
                   string Tipo_Calcado = txtTCalcado.Text;
                   string Tabagista = txtTabagista.Text;
                   string Eletista = txtElitista.Text;
                   string Pressao = txtPressao.Text;
                   string Cardiaca = txtCardiaca.Text;
                   string Respiratoria = txtRespiratoria.Text;
                   string Glicose = txtGlicose.Text;
                   string Altura = txtAltura.Text;
                   string Imc = txtImc.Text;
                   string Queixas = txtQueixas.Text;
                   string Hist_Familia = txtHFamiliar.Text;
                   string Doencas_Pres = txtDoencasPre.Text;
                   string Acidentes = txtAcidentes.Text;
                   string Alergias = txtAlergias.Text;
                   string Cirurgias = txtCirurgias.Text;
                   string Peso = txtPeso.Text;
                   int cd = Convert.ToInt32(cm.Parameters["@cd"].Value);



                    string strSql = "update tbl_Anamnese set ds_PosicaoTrab=@Pos_Trabalho, ds_TiposCal=@Tipo_Calcado, ds_Tabagista=@Tabagista, ds_Estilista=@Eletista, ds_PressaoArt=@Pressao, ds_Frecardiaca=@Cardiaca, ds_FreRespiratoria=@Respiratoria, ds_Glicose=@Glicose, ds_Altura=@Altura, ds_Peso=@Peso, ds_Imc=@Imc, ds_Queixas=@Queixas, ds_HistoricoFami=@Hist_Familia, ds_DoencasExist=@Doencas_Pres, ds_Acidentes=@Acidentes, ds_Alergias=@Alergias, ds_Cirurgias=@Cirurgias where id_Cliente=@cd"; 

                    cm.CommandText = strSql;
                    cm.Connection = cn;



                    cm.Parameters.Add("@cd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cd;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Pos_Trabalho", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Pos_Trabalho;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Tipo_Calcado", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Tipo_Calcado;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Tabagista", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Tabagista;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Eletista", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Eletista;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Pressao", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Pressao;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Cardiaca", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Cardiaca;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Respiratoria", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Respiratoria;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Glicose", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Glicose;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Altura", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Altura;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Imc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Imc;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Queixas", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Queixas;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Hist_Familia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Hist_Familia;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Doencas_Pres", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Doencas_Pres;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Acidentes", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Acidentes;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Alergias", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Alergias;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Cirurgias", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Cirurgias;
                    cm.Parameters.Add("@Peso", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Peso;
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd", 0).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cm.CommandText = "Inset into tbl_Anamnese(id_Cliente)value('" + cd + "')";

                    cn.Open();
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cm.Parameters.Clear();

                    LimparCampos();

                    DesabilitaCampos();

                    MessageBox.Show("Dados do cliente foram salvos com sucesso!", "Atualização de Cliente", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


                }

                catch (Exception erro)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
                    cn.Close();
                }

                finally
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LwGp.png

**Banco de dados SQL Server**

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNfPV.png

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d10Qj.png

Obrigado desde já,
agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Parece estar reclamando que a coluna @cd não existe, e
no print que voce mandou realmente não existe essa coluna;
verifica a linha

```
cm.Parameters.Add("@cd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cd;
```

Comment: Oi meu amigo, fiz essa tentativa que você mencionou, mas sem sucesso! Continua o mesmo erro

Comment: comentou a linha para ver se o erro muda?

Comment: Oi meu amigo, como assim ?

Comment: coloca // na frente da linha e o compilador vai ignorar ela. isso é comentar.
isso é uma das formas de adicionar comentários no seu código. caso o erro mude o problema está nessa linha.